# My Javascript flipbook code is working fine on Chrome but having problems on Firefox. How can I achieve the solution?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, javascript-objects

I have created a Flipbook using HTML, CSS3 and JavaScript. It **is working fine on Google Chrome** but it is not working properly on Firefox. I have Googled and tried to find answer. In most cases it is said that Firefox handle hoisting differently than Chrome. But there is no solution to it. Output is in the link below. If open with Chrome, it works fine but creates problems if opened with Firefox.

My code is:

```js
var front = document.querySelector('.face-front');
var back = document.querySelector('.face-back');
var flip = document.querySelector('.book-content');
var uno = document.querySelectorAll('.book');
var portada = document.querySelectorAll('#portada');

var contZindex = 2;
var customZindex = 1;

// javascript hoisting function starts

// javascript hoisting function ends


for(var i = 0; i < uno.length; i++){
  uno[i].style.zIndex = customZindex;
  customZindex--;

  uno[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var tgt = event.target;
    var unoThis = this;

    unoThis.style.zIndex = contZindex;
    contZindex++;

    if(tgt.getAttribute('class') == 'face-front'){
      unoThis.style.zIndex = contZindex;
      contZindex += 20;
      setTimeout(function(){
        unoThis.style.transform = 'rotateY(-180deg)';
      }, 500);
      // setTimeout(buntyTimeoutFront(), 500);

    }

    if(tgt.getAttribute('class') == 'face-back'){
      unoThis.style.zIndex = contZindex;
      contZindex += 20;
      setTimeout(function(){
        unoThis.style.transform = 'rotateY(-0deg)';
      }, 500);
      // setTimeout(buntyTimeoutBack(), 500);
    }

    if(tgt.getAttribute('id') == 'portada'){
      flip.classList.remove("trnsf-reset");
      flip.classList.add("trnsf");
    }

    if(tgt.getAttribute('id') == 'trsf'){
      flip.classList.remove("trnsf");
      flip.classList.add("trnsf-reset");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
*{
  pddding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


p{
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: justify;
}


/* classes for javascript starts*/



.trnsf{
  /* transform for diff browser starts */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(80px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(80px);
  -o-transform: translateX(80px);
  transform: translateX(80px);
  /* transform for diff browser ends */
}

.trnsf-reset{
  /* transform for diff browser starts */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
  -o-transform: translateX(0px);
  transform: translateX(0px);
  /* transform for diff browser ends */
}


/* classes for javascript ends*/


.container, .book-content{
  /* display flex starts*/
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* display flex ends*/
  /* justify-content starts */
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  /* justify-content ends */
  /* align items center */
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  /* align items center */
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #2d6f75;
}


.book-content{
  width: 65%;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 330px;
  position: relative;
  /* perspective for css starts */
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  -ms-perspective: 1000px;
  -o-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* perspective for css ends */
  transition: 1s;
}


.book{
  position: absolute;
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  /* transform-style starts  */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* transform-style ends  */
  /* transform-oregin starts  */
  transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  -moz-transform-origin: left;
  -ms-transform-origin: left;
  -o-transform-origin: left;
  /* transform-oregin ends  */
}


.face-front, .face-back{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.face-front{
  box-shadow: inset 3px 0px 20px -7px black;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}


.face-back{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* transform for diff browser starts */
  transform: translateZ(-1px) rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(-1px) rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(-1px) rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: translateZ(-1px) rotateY(180deg);
  /* transform for diff browser ends */
  box-shadow: inset -3px 1px 20px -7px black;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}


#portada{
  background: url('../images/front.jpg');
}

#portada-back{
  background: url('../images/back.jpg');
}

#portada, #portada-back{
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}




/* responsive part starts here */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  p{
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" id = "container">
        <div class="book-content">
          <!-- book container -->
          <div class="book">
            <div class="face-front" id = "portada"></div>
            <div class="face-back" id = "trsf">
              <h1>Title 1</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta cupiditate, at aut harum necessitatibus doloremque inventore dolores dolorem facilis quas consectetur, incidunt voluptatibus blanditiis assumenda ratione, culpa iusto exercitationem vel.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- book container -->
          <!-- book container -->
          <div class="book">
            <div class="face-front">
              <h1>Title 2</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta cupiditate, at aut harum necessitatibus doloremque inventore dolores dolorem facilis quas consectetur, incidunt voluptatibus blanditiis assumenda ratione, culpa iusto exercitationem vel.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="face-back">
              <h1>Title 3</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta cupiditate, at aut harum necessitatibus doloremque inventore dolores dolorem facilis quas consectetur, incidunt voluptatibus blanditiis assumenda ratione, culpa iusto exercitationem vel.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- book container -->
          <!-- book container -->
          <div class="book">
            <div class="face-front">
              <h1>Title 4</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta cupiditate, at aut harum necessitatibus doloremque inventore dolores dolorem facilis quas consectetur, incidunt voluptatibus blanditiis assumenda ratione, culpa iusto exercitationem vel.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="face-back">
              <h1>Title 5</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta cupiditate, at aut harum necessitatibus doloremque inventore dolores dolorem facilis quas consectetur, incidunt voluptatibus blanditiis assumenda ratione, culpa iusto exercitationem vel.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- book container -->

          <!-- book container -->
          <div class="book">
            <div class="face-front">
              <h1>Title 6</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta cupiditate, at aut harum necessitatibus doloremque inventore dolores dolorem facilis quas consectetur, incidunt voluptatibus blanditiis assumenda ratione, culpa iusto exercitationem vel.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="face-back" id = "portada-back"></div>
          </div>
          <!-- book container -->
        </div>
    </div>

  <script src = "js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is in the link below.
https://studyoob.com/myCustomFlipbook/

Your help would get me the project done.

Comment: Hey, nice output. I'm viewing on chrome and it looks very nice.

Comment: Thank you!. It works fine in chrome. but it doesn't properly in firefox. Please help me if you can.